# Traefik 2.0 and Docker set middleware without naming the router

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm using traefik 2.0 with docker provider (swarm mode) and I wish to provide a default way for services publishing themselves on traefik avoiding conflicts.

I managed to create a default rule matching my needs, but I'm now struggling because I don't see a way to provide a default middleware to strip away prefixes.

Is there a way to add a docker service label without having to provide a specific router name, but still adding a middleware to whatever router was implicitly created by traefik?
Or is there a way to define a default middleware as there is for the default rule?

The solution I'm trying to approach is to remove all the variable substitutions in the following labels, thus reducing the verbosity of the whole definition but without exposing myself to naming conflicts:

```
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.services.${ENV:-dev}_${STACK}_whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=80
        - traefik.http.middlewares.${ENV:-dev}_${STACK}_whoami.stripprefix.prefixes=/${STACK}
        - traefik.http.routers.${ENV:-dev}_${STACK}_whoami.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.${ENV:-dev}_${STACK}_whoami.rule=PathPrefix(`/${STACK}/whoami`)
        - traefik.http.routers.${ENV:-dev}_${STACK}_whoami.middlewares=${ENV:-dev}_${STACK}_whoami@docker
```

Hoping it could become something like the following, where `default` is the magic word for using the implicit service name assigned by Docker when deploying the stack:

```
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.services.default.loadbalancer.server.port=80
        - traefik.http.middlewares.default.stripprefix.prefixes=/${STACK}
        - traefik.http.routers.default.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.default.rule=PathPrefix(`/${STACK}/whoami`)
        - traefik.http.routers.default.middlewares=default@docker
```

I tried the following, but apparently the go template doesn't get replaced:

```
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.services.{{ .Name }}.loadbalancer.server.port=80
        - traefik.http.middlewares.{{ .Name }}.stripprefix.prefixes=/${STACK}
        - traefik.http.routers.{{ .Name }}.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.{{ .Name }}.rule=PathPrefix(`/${STACK}/whoami`)
        - traefik.http.routers.{{ .Name }}.middlewares={{ .Name }}@docker
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you explain the reason for downvoting the question when you feel the urge to do so.

Comment: I have had a similar problem. Using `--providers.docker.defaultrule` https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/reference/static-configuration/cli/ The host is easier to handle, but I don't want to have to make a globally unique name for each service/router/middleware unless they need to be shared. The naming convention that docker swarm uses should be fine `[stack name]_[service name]` but it seems like a lot of duplicated entry to add a unique service name for each.

Comment: The problem with using the default rule is I cannot specify a default middlewares: in the above I need to strip out the prefix and I need to do it for each service... I’m trying to set up something to be used by projects built by Jenkins pipelines and I probably end up with hundreds of stacks being deployed, one per each branch/pull-request. Setting up DNS names for each one is unfeasible

Comment: I don't know how to do default middleware yet. I am looking at their forum now community.containo.us

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested it but according to [this doc](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.1/providers/file/#go-templating), Go templating is only supported in dynamic (Yaml/Toml) configuration file.

So I suggest you try to add a dynamic configuration file [(see here)](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.1/providers/file/#filename) and write something like :

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    {{range $i, $e := until 100 }}
    router{{ $e }}:
      middlewares = {{ $e }}
    {{end}}
```

Hopes this can help

Comment: Sorry, if that creates 100 routers, each one with its own middleware than I don't think it can satisfy the requirement because I don't see how I can then assign these routers to different services, when I don't know the services beforehand

Comment: as described (here)[https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.1/providers/file/#go-templating], services could be templated as well. Also I think you might just be over-engineering your solution as just putting a default middleware seems to work for you, what I suggest is putting a middlewares on the secure 443 entrypoint ```web-secure:
    address: ":443"
    http:
      middlewares:
        - default@docker```

Comment: code doesn't look good in comments, see https://www.reddit.com/r/Traefik/comments/hqmpz5/how_to_negateremove_a_default_middleware/ for a prettier looking code discussing the topic

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to apply to my request because my middleware must strip a prefix, and the prefix changes depending on the target service. I might agree on the "over-engineering", but at this stage my solution uses an nginx redirecting toward traefik redirecting to the endpoint.... Which is even worse IMHO

Comment: I think you might be good using stripprefixregex to get the prefix that change and store it in a header for later use (if needed). You can put the middleware on the endpoint to make it apply to all services. Also if you know a bit of Go you can write your own plugin as middleware (https://doc.traefik.io/traefik-pilot/plugins/plugin-dev/)